# Jstl <c:when > syntax

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am updating user status(true,false) form jsp page , here i am getting user status from controller class and displayed in option box , here i am using `<c:when>` jstl tag. see the below code

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${roamingDenied == 'True')">
        <option value="True" selected>True</option>
        <option value="False">False</option>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <option value="True">True</option>
        <option value="False" selected>False</option>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

above code always displayed "False", plz any one give me suggestion for that..

Answer (score 2):

The condition should be just

`${roamingDenied}`

or

`${roamingDenied == true}`

Also, there is a typo in your expression. It should be within `{`and `}`. Yours ends in a `)`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of the value of attribute roamingDenied.
Perhaps your roamingDenied is boolean not String like adarshr adviced.